# qsub doesn't recognize awk field variables

Tags: awk, qsub

Consider this awk script to print column #2 of every line:
`awk '{print $2}' a.txt`. $2 is not a shell variable, yet when I attempt to submit this code to qsub, $2 is interpreted as such. I.e.

`qsub awk '{print $2}' a.txt`

results in qsub executing the command

`awk '{print }' a.txt`

To be clear, I'm *not* trying to use a shell variable in an awk script; therefore [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) is not applicable.

I tried suggestions in [Using awk with qsub and issues with quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55264985/using-awk-with-qsub-and-issues-with-quotations), including `\$2` and

`qsub -- awk '{print $2}' a.txt`.

Neither works.

I can certainly put awk in a script and call qsub that way, i.e., `qsub awkscript.sh`. However, if there's a way to use qsub+awk from the command line, I'd like to learn how.

Comment: I've never heard of `qsub` but you could try `qsub "awk '{print \$2}' a.txt"` or `qsub 'awk \"{print \$2}\" a.txt'`. You may need to add or remove backslashes in front of the `$2`.

Comment: Thanks for asking. None of these work, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm speachless, I'd never heard of `qsub`, but for @EdMorton -- now I know we are down in the weeds. So `qsub` (I have the man page), is the user utility to submit a script for background processing by a batch server. 21 years using Linux and I somehow have gotten along without it `:)`

Comment: It's fairly specific to high-performance computing batch environments, but pretty ubiquitous in those.

Answer (score 1):

does a double-layer quoting work, like

```
qsub 'awk '\''{ print $2 }'\'' a.txt '
```

Comment: This works, with a minor change (backspash before $): `qsub 'awk '\''{ print \$2 }'\'' a.txt '`

Comment: ahhh thanks. i never even heard of qsub so i was only guestimating the solution off the top of my head

Answer (score 0):

RARE Kpop Manifesto below was 99% correct. With a backslash, the whole expression worked like magic :)

`qsub 'awk '\''{ print \$2 }'\'' a.txt '`